# UWP: BluetoothDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync throws 0x80070002 exception on non-discoverable & unpaired BT device

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, win-universal-app, pairing

I'm trying to pair from a Universal Windows C# app to a Bluetooth - Serial converter, without user interaction.

Development is in Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 10 Pro, but app is intended to run in any Windows 10 based device with a Bluetooth adapter.

For security reasons, BT-serial converter isn't discoverable and is protected by a pin, so I'm not able to perform any enumeration procedure to detect and pair it.

My application only knows BT address (MAC) and PIN's device (Also it knows friendly Bluetooth name, but I never used it).

Previously I'd been able to perform this task under Windows Mobile 6 Pocket PC, using Windows Mobile SDK and C++, but unfortunately code isn't portable to Universal Windows Platform.

Playing with MS samples for Universal Windows(https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) I achieved to write a code that achieves to pair device, creating from strings some objects that in source sample are derived from enumeration process.

But it only works if device is visible. This is the code:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace UWPBTTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            DoPairing();
        }

        async public void DoPairing()
        {            
            UInt64 targetMAC = 32217180653; //target MAC in decimal, this number corresponds to my device (00:07:80:4b:29:ed)
            BluetoothDevice btDev = await BluetoothDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(targetMAC); //We create target BT device object, here app throws 0x80070002 exception
            DeviceInformation infDev = btDev.DeviceInformation; //We need this aux object to perform pairing
            DevicePairingKinds ceremoniesSelected = DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly | DevicePairingKinds.ProvidePin; //Only confirm pairing, we'll provide PIN from app
            DevicePairingProtectionLevel protectionLevel = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Encryption; //Encrypted connection
            DeviceInformationCustomPairing customPairing = infDev.Pairing.Custom; //Our app takes control of pairing, not OS
            customPairing.PairingRequested += PairingRequestedHandler; //Our pairing request handler
            DevicePairingResult result = await customPairing.PairAsync(ceremoniesSelected, protectionLevel); //launc pairing
            customPairing.PairingRequested -= PairingRequestedHandler;
            if ((result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.Paired) || (result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.AlreadyPaired))
            {
                //success, now we are able to open a socket
            }
            else
            {
                //pairing failed
            }

        }

        //Adapted from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing , scenario 9
        private async void PairingRequestedHandler(
            DeviceInformationCustomPairing sender,
            DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.PairingKind)
            {
                case DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly:
                    // Windows itself will pop the confirmation dialog as part of "consent" if this is running on Desktop or Mobile
                    // If this is an App for 'Windows IoT Core' where there is no Windows Consent UX, you may want to provide your own confirmation.
                    args.Accept();
                    break;

                case DevicePairingKinds.ProvidePin:
                    // As function must be asyn, we simulate a delay of 1 second on GetPinAsync
                    var collectPinDeferral = args.GetDeferral();
                    string pin = "1234"; //BT converter pin, currently is "1234" for testing purposes
                    args.Accept(pin);
                    collectPinDeferral.Complete();
                    break;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

This prototype app uses a blank form, as all data are hardcoded.
Also in Package.appxmanifest -> Capabilities, I checked all fields to discard any permission lack.

Currently this code only can perform pairing operation if BT-serial converter is visible.
If BT device isn't visible, BluetoothDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync throws an exception (Resource not found: 0x80070002), instead of creating the BluetoothDevice object.

Is as if Windows "needed" to know something of BT device in order to perform operation, I suspect that when I call FromBluetoothAddressAsync, OS internally lists all devices in system (this includes detected BT devices in range) looking for and item with given address.

I've been looking for other methods to perform mac-based pairing against hidden bt devices, but without success (maybe some type of "pre-pairing"? I didn't find anything)

Thanks.